# Riak - Connection Refused while trying to connect to Riak cluster using Python client library

Tags: python, http, protocol-buffers, riak, connection-refused

I am a Riak newbie. I installed Riak 2.1.1 from the source on my local machine while following instructions at: https://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/mac-osx/

I then started three nodes and pinged all the three nodes and received 'pong' as the response.

I joined then joined the three nodes to create a cluster. Checking the cluster member status:

```
dev1/bin/riak-admin member-status
================================= Membership ==================================
Status     Ring    Pending    Node
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
valid      34.4%      --      'dev1@127.0.0.1'
valid      32.8%      --      'dev2@127.0.0.1'
valid      32.8%      --      'dev3@127.0.0.1'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Valid:3 / Leaving:0 / Exiting:0 / Joining:0 / Down:0
```

I looked at the riak.config file in rel/riak/etc/ directory and saw that the following has been set:

```
## listener.http.<name> is an IP address and TCP port that the Riak
## HTTP interface will bind.
## 
## Default: 127.0.0.1:8098
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011
listener.http.internal = 127.0.0.1:8098

## listener.protobuf.<name> is an IP address and TCP port that the Riak
## Protocol Buffers interface will bind.
## 
## Default: 127.0.0.1:8087
## 
## Acceptable values:
##   - an IP/port pair, e.g. 127.0.0.1:10011
listener.protobuf.internal = 127.0.0.1:8087
```

I then installed the Riak python client using pip. I am following the Riak python client docs at http://riak-python-client.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.0/client.html.

The following is my Python script:

```
import riak

client = riak.RiakClient(pb_port=8087,protocol='pbc')

print 'finished'

user_bucket = client.bucket('user')

val1 = 1
key1 = user_bucket.new('one', data=val1)
key1.store()

print 'finished2'
```

However, running the python script gives the following error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/riak/security.py:35: UserWarning: Found OpenSSL 0.9.8zd 8 Jan 2015 version, but expected at least OpenSSL 1.0.1g.  Security may not support TLS 1.2.
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
finished
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/project/RiakDataLoader/src/DataLoader.py", line 11, in <module>
    **key1.store()**
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/riak/riak_object.py", line 286, in store
    timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 196, in wrapper
    return self._with_retries(pool, thunk)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/riak/client/transport.py", line 151, in _with_retries
    raise e.args[0]
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

All my nodes were running before I ran the python script.

I then tried the following command on the terminal using the http port:

```
$ curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:8098/buckets/welcome/keys/german  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain'  -d 'herzlich willkommen'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8098: Connection refused
```

What may be the cause of this connection refused error? Have been chasing this problem for hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running the three nodes on the same machine? And executing the Python code / curl on that machine, too? Could you clarify please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using several dev nodes the config files will be under the `dev` directory, such as `dev/dev1/etc/riak.conf`.  You'll need to check there to see which ports are being used for the protocol buffers listener for each node..  The configuration under the `rel` directory is only suitable for running a single node on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced a similar issue but couldn't find a solution which was straight forward.

When you do a `riak stop` without leaving the cluster there are files which are present in the ring directory which need to be deleted since the `riak start/sudo service riak start` command triggers read from the ring information.

The default location of the riak ring directory is `/var/lib/riak/ring/`
delete the files here and do a `riak start`.

Note if the node in question is a master node for the cluster you will have to -

1. Do all of the above for the master node ( stop clean ring ) and -
2. Remove the nodes from the cluster using the `riak-admin cluster leave`
3. Stop the riak nodes using `riak stop`
4. delete the ring directory as mentioned above
5. do a `riak start`
6. follow rules to set up the cluster again using `riak-admin`

These would be viable in non-production situations.